# Error selecting a column after grouping the dataframe using group_by from dplyr 0.3.02

Tags: r, dplyr

I cannot select the second column after grouping the data.frame

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(1))
d[,2] # selects the second column
d <- group_by(d, x)
d[,2] # produces the error: index out of bounds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* this is intended behavior in dplyr for a `grouped_df` object - the logic being that the grouping variable(s) cannot be dropped while the data is still grouped. Consider this example where I use dplyr's `select` function to extract variables from a `grouped_df`:

```
require(dplyr)
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(1), z  = rnorm(2))
d <- group_by(d, x)

select(d, y)  
#Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
#Groups: x
#
#    x         y
#1   1 0.5861766
#2   2 0.5861766
#3   3 0.5861766
#4   4 0.5861766
#5   5 0.5861766
#6   6 0.5861766
#7   7 0.5861766
#8   8 0.5861766
#9   9 0.5861766
#10 10 0.5861766
```

You can see that the result includes the grouping variable even though it was not specified in the `select` call.

```
select(d, z) # would work the same way
```

Even if you explicitly excluded the grouping variable "x", it would still be returned when using `select`:

```
select(d, -x)
#Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
#Groups: x
#
#    x         y         z
#1   1 0.2110696 2.4393919
#2   2 0.2110696 0.8400083
#3   3 0.2110696 2.4393919
#4   4 0.2110696 0.8400083
#5   5 0.2110696 2.4393919
#6   6 0.2110696 0.8400083
#7   7 0.2110696 2.4393919
#8   8 0.2110696 0.8400083
#9   9 0.2110696 2.4393919
#10 10 0.2110696 0.8400083
```

To get only the "y" column, you would need to ungroup the data first:

```
ungroup(d) %>% select(y)
#Source: local data frame [10 x 1]
#
#           y
#1  0.5861766
#2  0.5861766
#3  0.5861766
#4  0.5861766
#5  0.5861766
#6  0.5861766
#7  0.5861766
#8  0.5861766
#9  0.5861766
#10 0.5861766
```

Note that you could use any subsetting with `[` that includes the grouping variable(s), for example:

```
d[, 1:2]
```

Or

```
d[, c(1,3)]
```