# Does grouping a data.fram using dplyr affect any other operations except dplyr verbs?

Tags: r, dplyr

Maybe this a redundant question but I was a bit curious after looking at the following question: [Error selecting a column after grouping the dataframe using group_by from dplyr 0.3.02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969365/error-selecting-a-column-after-grouping-the-dataframe-using-group-by-from-dplyr/37819414#37819414).

This does not seem to be an issue in later versions of dplyr. When rerunning the example (dplyr 0.4.3) I do not get the "Index out of bounds" message and I am able to select the column (albeit with a slightly different presentation of the output).

However, it made me wonder if a grouped data.frame can lead to unexpected results outside of using dplyr verbs (which would hopefully lead to expected results)?

This for example seems to yield the exact same results:

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
group_cyl<-group_by(mtcars, cyl)
summary(lm(mpg~hp, mtcars))
summary(lm(mpg~hp, group_cyl))
```

While this obviously does not:

```
summarise(mtcars, mean(hp))
summarise(group_cyl, mean(hp))
```

Comment: Sure, `groups(group_by(mtcars, cyl))` works, but `groups` is not a verb. If you're looking for a thorough enumeration of all the things affected by `group_by`, you might want to read the source code for `group_by` and the rest of the dplyr package.

Comment: For the most part, only functions that import the dplyr namespace are likely to handle the grouping. The "only thing" (simplified) that `group_by` does is assign a set of attributes to the data so that later calcs in the pipeline don't have to re-calculate grouping (see `str(attributes(group_by(mtcars, cyl)))`).

Comment: Occassionally you will make what seems to be a perfectly coded ggplot that doesn't work as expected until I try using `ungroup()`. I'm not sure what specific conditions cause this but it is a best practice to `ungroup()` after a `group_by()`.